# Can't add new sharepoint 2013 connections in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to add a new Sharepoint Connections in Visual Studio 2015 and I get this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0CFk.png) :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Sharepoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies.

I have yet installed Sharepoint 2013 SDK and Sharepoint client components, and I have some Sharepoint DLL in my folder :

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\ISAPI

I'm trying to do that to create a workflow on a remote Sharepoint 2013 server, and I can't either create a new Workflow project because remote Server debugging is not supported... (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj3dT.png)

I also have the same error when I'm trying to create a new projet.

Is there a way to fix these problems ?

Note that we have a Sharepoint **foundation** server 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sharepoint is installed in the remote server and you want to debug that code in your local environment then you need to follow below given steps.

1. Create a wsp for your project
2. Deploy it using the stsadm command or add/deploy solution from the Poweshell
3. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger
4. Copy whole folder in your remote server
5. Start msvsmon.exe as run as administrator in the remote server.
6. Go to your visual studio and Click on Tools -> Attach to Process
7. Select Transport dropdown and select Remote in it
8. Click on Find button
9. You will get a name of your Remote server 
   10.Select it and hit ok.
10. Now you can debug your code using the remote debugger.

Comment: Ok, but how can I create a wsp file if I can't even create a Sharepoint projet in Visual studio 2013 ? It sends me the same error as when I try to create a new Workflow project. (Sorry if I miss something that seems obvious, but I'm starting with Sharepoint development and I am a bit lost)

Comment: Do you have sharepoint installed locally , Foundation version will be feasible. ? If not then you need to hop on the server with sharepoint and then create that wsp and then from that server follow the steps as above

Comment: I don't have a sharepoint installed locally. Would it be easier if I install one in local ? Or do I have to install Visual Studio on the sharepoint server ? I only find deployment tutorials on the Internet but not how to create that wsp file from the server